# Validation - document type does not allow element "h4" here

Tags: html, validation

I can't find out what the problem is with this line of code:

```
<h4><span class="orange">mytitle</span></h4>
```

This is the error message I receive:

> document type does not allow element
>   "h4" here;

What do I need to change?
Cheers
Mic

Comment: What is the surrounding HTML?

Comment: It means that it's not valid in whatever context it's in; you'll need to post more of your markup for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: What kind of element is your h4 inside of? A <p> tag, maybe?

Comment: The error says "document type does not allow element "h4" **here**", but you haven't said where *here* is!

Comment: and [don't use `class="orange"`](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h4>` (like all headers) is a block level element. You've probably put it directly inside something that doesn't allow it, like `<table>` or `<tr>` or an inline element (`<span>`, `<a>` ).

Comment: Thank you! I used it inside a <span class=""> - It's fixed now.