# error in validating : document type does not allow element "h4" here; assuming missing "li" start-tag

Tags: html

I'm getting the following error while validating my website:

document type does not allow element X here; assuming missing Y start-tag ✉
Line 65, column 17: document type does not allow element "h4" here; assuming missing "li" start-tag

```
            <h4><b>Groep 1</b></h4>
```

the piece of code it's in is this:

```
<div class="leftsidebar">
    <ul class="nav">
            <h4><b>Groep 1</b></h4>

        <li><a href="leftnavbar/link1.html">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="leftnavbar/link2.html">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="leftnavbar/link3.html">Link 3</a>
        </li>
         <h4><b>Groep 2</b></h4>

        <li><a href="leftnavbar/link4.html">Link 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="leftnavbar/link5.html">Link 5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="leftnavbar/link6.html">Link 6</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p id="leftnavbartext">"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio etc etc etc</p>
</div>
```

I've looked up some info in another thread ([Validation - document type does not allow element "h4" here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060812/validation-document-type-does-not-allow-element-h4-here)) which says that  (like all headers) is a block level element. You've probably put it directly inside something that doesn't allow it, like  or  or an inline element (,  ).

But on my website it does show the text in the h4 format. Why is this? And is there a way to fix this?

Website: www.seandorsman.nl

Browser: Google Chrome

Thanks in advance!

Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation on the UL element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) :

> Content model:
>
> Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.

You can't put a H4 element inside a UL element.

Comment: That I figured out, but i am wondering why it still shows "correct" on my website.

Comment: What do you want the browser to do ? To tell you there is incorrect HTML on your site ? Most web sites in the world are incorrect.

Comment: Well, i'd expect that if it's not possible, that it would show it in a normal font, not a header.

because now my browser tells me there is "correct" html, since it is the way I want it to be.

Comment: The browser tries to do the best it can, without giving any guarantee past what is normalized. Simply put your H4 outside the UL.